# How to properly run remote powershell script with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, asp.net-web-api

i have back.ps1 script that connecting to api getting token to gain acces to another api for getting json from database and with this json the back.ps1 script 
knows how to rar some remote files and upload it to ftp server
every thing is working good when i am running the script on the server

i am trying to run it through C# ASP.NET WEB API function :

```
public static bool RunBackupWWWROOTPowerShellScript() {


        string password = "someuser";
        string userName = "somepassword";

        SecureString securepassword = String2SecureString(password);
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securepassword);
        WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://someserver:5985/wsman"), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", credential);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Negotiate;
        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
        {
            try
            {
                runspace.Open();
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

                var powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;

                string scriptfile = "C:\\backup.ps1";

                powershell.AddScript(scriptfile);
                powershell.Invoke();

                Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject output in results)
                {
                        //sending powershell output to signalr
                        hubs.Clients.All.SendPowerShellResults(output);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }
```

Backup.ps1 :

```
  $rar = "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe"
  $currentdate = get-date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
  $mysqlcurrentdate = get-date -Format "yyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss"
  $GetToken =  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://someserver/api/Authentication?username=someuser&password=somepassword" | ConvertFrom-Json

  $token = $GetToken .access_token

  $BackupJson = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://someserver/api/Admin/GetBackupJson" -Header @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $token" } | ConvertFrom-Json


  foreach($server in $BackupJson)
  {
      $serverip = $server.ip
      $servername = $server.Name
      $mainbackuplocation = $server.mainbackuplocation
      $query = "UPDATE BackupStatus SET Status='Creating RAR',lastbackup='$mysqlcurrentdate' WHERE Name='$servername'"
MySQLandSignalR $query

   }
```

let say that MySQLandSignalR function is not working (its supposed to update database with the query)

i can see that the script is running on the server but its broke and not working like it should
all the function inside backup.ps1 are not working and i dont know why

any suggestion about how to do it properly ?

thanks !

Comment: If you step through the `C#` code are there any errors in `results`?

Comment: no ...its working fine
for example all the rar function inside the script is working but its not rar the right files and its not update the database its seems like some function or parameters are ignored

Comment: That makes it sound like the issue may be with the script rather than the `c#` stuff - are you able to post the script you are trying to run, or at least the parts that are not working?

Comment: i updated the post with the backup.ps1 script

Comment: If you execute the `PowerShell` script manually, does it run correctly?

Comment: yep everything working just fine